# Check pandas df2.colA for occurrences of df1.id and write (df2.colB, df2.colC) into df1.colAB

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, matching

I have two pandas `df` and they do not have the same length. `df1` has unique id's in column `id`. These id's occur (multiple times) in `df2.colA`. I'd like to add a list of all occurrences of `df1.id` in `df2.colA` (and another column at the matching index of `df1.id == df2.colA`) into a new column in `df1`. Either with the index of `df2.colA` of the match or additionally with other row entries of all matches.

Example:

```
df1.id = [1, 2, 3, 4]

df2.colA = [3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1] 

df2.colB = [5, 9, 6, 5, 8, 7]
```

So that my operation creates something like:

```
df1.colAB = [ [[1,8],[1,7]], [[2,5]], [[3,5]], [[4,9],[4,6]] ]
```

I've tries a bunch of approaches with mapping, looping explicitly (super slow), checking with `isin` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Pandas [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) to iterate over each row of `df1` value while creating a list with all the indices in `df2.colA`. This can be achieved by using Pandas `index` and [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) over the `df2.colB` to create a list with all the indices in `df2.colA` that match the row in `df1.id`. Then, within the `apply` itself use a for-loop to create the list of matched values.

```py
import pandas as pd
# setup
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4]})
print(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'colA' : [3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1],
        'colB' : [5, 9, 6, 5, 8, 7]
})
print(df2)

#code
df1['colAB'] = df1['id'].apply(lambda row:
        [[row, idx] for idx in df2.loc[df2[df2.colA == row].index,'colB']])

print(df1)
```

Output from *df1*

```py
   id             colAB
0   1  [[1, 8], [1, 7]]
1   2          [[2, 5]]
2   3          [[3, 5]]
3   4  [[4, 9], [4, 6]]
```